# Jquery - Call a js function when page loaded

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden div on my page that is displayed when a control function is called.
I'd like to show the div when the whole page has been loaded (inside the DOM?) or called with 2 second delay because sometimes when the page (with images) is reloaded the function is called and then disappears when the page is loaded also if the php if condition is changed (mysqlquery result = 2)

MY PHP PAGE

```
if(mysqlquery result = 1) { 

echo '<script>'; 
echo "$(function(){ ShowAlertBox(); });";
echo '</script>';

}
```

MY JS PAGE

```
// # DOM Ready
$( function() {
...
...
}); <!-- end DOM -->

function ShowAlertBox(){
   $('.alert').show("slow");
}
```

What would be the best way to fix and to do this? Thanks

EDIT

i try in this way but the function is not called

```
// # DOM Ready
$( function() {

    function ShowAlertBox(){
    $('.alert').show("slow");
    }

}); <!-- end DOM -->
```

Comment: js inside a php page !! mmm sounds bad !

Comment: There is no need to create such a question on StackOverflow. This is a basic functionality and if you'd have searched you'd knew it wasn't that hard. Here is a page to their API http://api.jquery.com either search or press `CTRL F` and search the document for a specific keywoard like `DOM` or `Load`.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate your function with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //Your code
});
```

This is telling the browser to wait until all assets have been loaded before your function is called

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mKJLr/1/)

Comment: I tried to put the function inside the document ready function, but the function is not called. What is the right syntax? thanks

Comment: @PaoloRossi I added a JSFiddle example with a setTimeout addition.  The hidden DIV will start appearing 2 seconds after the page loads

Comment: Is it safe to asume that you loaded jquery?

Comment: @LloydBanks thanks but how can I call my function (ShowAlertBox) inside document ready with timeout?

Comment: @PaoloRossi Replace the "$('.alert').show("slow");" with "ShowAlertBox();". I updated the fiddle link. The new version shows the function being called

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   //Code should go here.
   $('.alert').show("slow");   // Show your alert box.
});
```

But please read the basics of jQuery.  Also, please go through with the documentation of `method`  jQuery() :    [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Answer (score 0):

The below code is execute when the entire page has been loaded (All DOM!)...

```
$(window).load(function(){
 // right down your code here...
});
```

I hope this will help you.